# Cassandra without jvm

Tags: jvm, nosql, cassandra

I have a question:
can install database Cassandra without java virtual machine? Or you must have virtual machine to run Cassandra? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted :

**Step 0: Prerequisites and connection to the community**

Cassandra requires the most stable version of Java 1.6 you can deploy. For Sun's jvm, this means at least u19; u21 is better. Cassandra also runs on the IBM jvm, and should run on jrockit as well.